# How to Implement arguments using System Property?

Tags: java, arguments, command-line-arguments

I want my program to get the path of some config file in as an argument. I wondering if i can implement using the system.getproperty. This is what the code looks like

```
String strBaseDir=System.getProperty("ConfigFilePath","C:\\Met_w\\StarCode\\source\\W\\config");
```

Idea of me using this is, to use -DConfigFilePath= "PATH" as an argument and when there is no argument the default path would be "C:\Met_w\StarCode\source\W\config". Can you please comment if its correct or not. Or anyother way to implement this.

Comment: what you have done, is correct. You can set 'ConfigFilePath' using the '-D' option and you can retrieve it using 'getProperty', providing the default value in case its 'null'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the system property before getting it. What you have is default value

```
System.getProperty(propertyString,defaultValue);
```

Your -DConfigFilePath= "PATH" your PATH should also have \\

You can do it the way you are doing it or you can have a java class read from a file and set it using [System.setProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))